# How to turn the result of summary() into a nice looking data table

Tags: r

Using R's summary(), I want to make a table that has means, std, n, min, and max for multiple variables.  I will use mtcars as a dataset (R's default dataset).  If just one variable, this worked well:

```
as.data.frame(t(unclass(summary(mtcars$disp))))
```

The result:

```
Min. 1st Qu. Median     Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
1 71.1 120.825  196.3 230.7219     326  472
```

If more than one, it doesn't work well.  I'm getting the same result as above (only the result for mtcars$disp shows).

```
as.data.frame(t(unclass(summary(mtcars$disp,mtcars$hp,mtcars$drat))))
```

The result (the same as above):
  Min. 1st Qu. Median     Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
1 71.1 120.825  196.3 230.7219     326  472

The ideal result should look like this.

```
Min. 1st Qu. Median     Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
71.1 120.825  196.3 230.7219     326  472
52    96.5    123 146.6875     180  335
2.76    3.08  3.695 3.596563    3.92 4.93
```

I would like the name of variables too:

```
Name  Min. 1st Qu. Median     Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
disp  71.1 120.825  196.3 230.7219     326  472
hp    52    96.5    123 146.6875     180  335
drat  2.76    3.08  3.695 3.596563    3.92 4.93
```

Could you advise?  Also in the last code, I have to repeat $mtcars many times.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Thank you.

I ask a similar question here, but the suggested codes are getting very complicated.  I'd like to stick with summary() if possible.
[R question: how to save summary results into a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57024367/r-question-how-to-save-summary-results-into-a-dataset/57024615#57024615)

Comment: Anyone know if the broom package covers this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `sapply` over the columns and get `summary` for each

```
cols <- c("disp", "hp", "drat")
t(sapply(mtcars[cols], summary))

#      Min. 1st Qu.  Median       Mean 3rd Qu.   Max.
#disp 71.10 120.825 196.300 230.721875  326.00 472.00
#hp   52.00  96.500 123.000 146.687500  180.00 335.00
#drat  2.76   3.080   3.695   3.596563    3.92   4.93
```

If you also need the names in a separate column

```
summary_df <- data.frame(t(sapply(mtcars[cols], summary)), check.names = FALSE)
summary_df$Name <- rownames(summary_df)
rownames(summary_df) <- NULL

summary_df
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median       Mean 3rd Qu.   Max. Name
#1 71.10 120.825 196.300 230.721875  326.00 472.00 disp
#2 52.00  96.500 123.000 146.687500  180.00 335.00   hp
#3  2.76   3.080   3.695   3.596563    3.92   4.93 drat
```

---

To add some additional statistics, we need to create a custom function

```
custom_summary <- function(x) {
  c(summary(x), length = length(x), nonmissing = sum(!is.na(x)), 
                sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}
t(sapply(mtcars[cols], custom_summary))

#      Min. 1st Qu.  Median       Mean 3rd Qu.   Max. length nonmissing          sd
#disp 71.10 120.825 196.300 230.721875  326.00 472.00     32         32 123.9386938
#hp   52.00  96.500 123.000 146.687500  180.00 335.00     32         32  68.5628685
#drat  2.76   3.080   3.695   3.596563    3.92   4.93     32         32   0.5346787
```

Comment: This looks great!

Comment: I like this approach because it's very simple.  I want to add the number of cases to the table.  How do I control what I can add to the summary() results?  Thank you!

Comment: @Kaz What other cases you want to add to the output? `summary` only returns the values shown in the answer above. If you need to add something else in that case you would need to write a custom function for that.

Comment: I want to add "the number of rows."  The dataset mtcars includes 32 cases, so the result should say n=32.

Comment: @Kaz Updated the answer to include `n`.

Comment: I added the part that adds n.  I get number of rows in the dataset (my dataset that I am analyzing) regardless of missing values.  I would like n to be the number of nonmissing values.  Could you advise?

Comment: @Kaz Yes, see updated answer with `non_missing_vals`. Here it shows same as `no_rows` because `mtcars` has no missing values.

Comment: Thank you.  I forgot to ask you one more thing.  I would like SD (standard deviation) from this.  My goal is to create a table that has n, min, max, mean, SD for multiple variables.  Thank you.

Comment: @Kaz you just need to add another variable in the function to calculate `sd`. See the update.

Comment: I'm getting all missing values from this SD function.  Is it because my variables have missing values?

Comment: @Kaz yes, you need to add `na.rm = TRUE` in `sd`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dplyr` and `summarise()`, which will output a tidy tibble/data.frame and and you can easily specify which summary stats you want.

```r
mtcars %>% select(disp,hp,drat) %>% 
  gather(k,v) %>% group_by(k) %>% 
  summarise(min=min(v),median=median(v),mean=mean(v),max=max(v),n=n())

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  k       min median   mean    max     n
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1 disp  71.1  196.   231.   472       32
2 drat   2.76   3.70   3.60   4.93    32
3 hp    52    123    147.   335       32
```